# Pandas: Issue with min() on Categorical columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following df where columns A,B,C are categorical variables with strict ordering:

```
df = DataFrame([[0, 1, 'PASS', 'PASS', 'PASS'],
                [0, 2, 'CHAIN', 'FAIL', 'PASS'],
                [0, 3, 'PASS', 'PASS', 'TATPG'],
                [0, 4, 'FAIL', 'PASS', 'FAIL'],
                [0, 5, 'FAIL', 'ATPG', 'FAIL']],
                columns = ['X', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
for c in ['A','B','C']:
     df[c] = df[c].astype('category', categories=['CHAIN', 'ATPG', 'TATPG', 'PASS', 'FAIL'], ordered=True)`
```

I want to create a new column D which is defined by the min('A', 'B', 'C'). For example, row 1 says 'CHAIN'. That is the smallest value. Hence, D[1] = CHAIN and so on. The D column should result as follows:

```
D[0] = PASS, D[1] = CHAIN, D[2] = TPATG, D[3] = PASS, D[4] = ATPG
```

I tried:

```
df['D'] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(min, axis=1)
```

However, this does not work as apply() makes the A/B/C column become of type object and hence min() sorts the values lexicographically instead of the ordering that I provided.

I also tried:

```
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].transpose().min(axis=0)
```

tranpose() too results in the columns A/B/C getting changed to type object instead of category.

Any ideas on how to do this correctly? I'd rather not recast the columns as categorical a 2nd time if using apply(). In general, I'll be creating a bunch of indicator columns using this formula:

```
df[indicator] = df[[any subset of (A,B,C)]].min()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that applies `sorted` with keys:

```
d = {'CHAIN': 0,
     'ATPG': 1,
     'TATPG': 2,
     'PASS': 3,
     'FAIL':4}

def func(row):
    return sorted(row, key=lambda x:d[x])[0]

df['D'] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(func, axis=1)
```

It gives you the result you're looking for:

```
0     PASS
1    CHAIN
2    TATPG
3     PASS
4     ATPG
```

However it does not make use of panda's native sorting of categorical variables.